# Android - Sync contacts and save into SQLite strategy

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Server - Linux CentOS + Python Flask + MongoDB

I am building an application that serve an auto-sync contacts.

**First signed user**

```
1. A user install the Android application.
2. The application imports all contacts and send it to server.
3. Server checks signed friends list and send it back to Android device.
4. Signed friend list and unsigned friend list save into SQLlite of Android device.
```

This work fine.

**Sync updated contacts**

```
1. Android application check the device contacts whether if he or she has new contacts.
2. If there is new contacts, application imports new contacts and send it to server.
3. Server checks if new contacts are signed users or not.
4. Server send the result back to device and update into SQLite
```

This is my strategy so far.

I am trying to find the best way to sync updated contacts and reduce operation time.

Do you have any knowledge about this? or is there a document that I can get a hint?

Thank you.

Comment: did you find any solution for it?